# How to compare a sentence in a list with all the sentence appearing after it in Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am having a list which has 1200 sentences. I want to compute the Jaccard coefficient of a sentence in a list with all the other sentences after it. 
Like sent1 will be compared with sent2,3,... Then sent2 with sent3,4,...
I already have a function that takes 2 sets and returns the Jaccard coefficient. I just want to know how to write the python loops for the above scenario.

```
list_question=[] #This List is later filled with sentences from a file

def jaccard(a,b): # computes Jaccard
    c=a.intersection(b)
    return float(len(c))/(len(a)+len(b)-len(c))

# ....Here i want to write the loop to compute the jaccard of sentences as explained in the question
```

I want to form a cluster of sentences which are similar based on the Jaccard Coeff score > 0.5

Thanks

Comment: share your code with us, no one will start from scratch for you

Comment: Use 2 loops with the inner one being initialized by the present position of the 1st one. Something like `for i ...`, `for j in range(i,...`

Comment: The first step to writing a program is to understand the problem you are trying to solve and describe a solution. I find that it often helps to turn off my computer and get a pen and paper. Then I write **in words** the steps I need to follow to solve the problem. Only after I have a clear solution do I get back on my computer and start translating it into code.

Comment: Please add some sample examples. This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It would be helpful to know the desired output and what you want to do with those Jaccard coefficients.

Comment: @AkashGupta Added the code snippet

Comment: @HansMusgrave I have Added the purpose of computing jaccard coeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [itertools.combination](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) like this:

```
import itertools

def do_some_stuff(first, second):
    print('comapring', first, 'to', second)

sentences_list = ['fisrt', 'second', 'third', 'forth']
combinations = itertools.combinations(sentences_list, 2)
for first, second in combinations:
    do_some_stuff(first, second)
```

The snippet above would give you this output:

```
comapring fisrt to second
comapring fisrt to third
comapring fisrt to forth
comapring second to third
comapring second to forth
comapring third to forth
```